# Compact for array two dimensions in Ruby

Tags: ruby

As we know compact in Array, it works like this :

```
[ "a", nil, "b", nil, "c", nil ].compact
              #=> [ "a", "b", "c" ]
```

Is there a function similar to do that for an array two dimentions ?

```
  [[nil, nil], ["Prestation Standard", 1]].compact => [["Prestation Standard", 1]]
```

Comment: See my comment on @Stefan's answer. You need to edit the question to make it clear whether you want to remove empty arrays and `nil`s as well as arrays that contain one or more `nil`s and no other objects.

Comment: @孙悟空 : Be careful with the wording: Threre are no two-dimensional arrays in Ruby. Of course you have **nested** arrays, but then it is not clear, what should be the intended outcome of compacting, say, `[[[nil],nil],[:x]]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would work:

```
ary = [[nil, nil], ["Prestation Standard", 1]]

ary.map(&:compact).reject(&:empty?)
#=> [["Prestation Standard", 1]]
```

`map(&:compact)` returns a new 2D array with all `nil` values removed from the inner arrays and `reject(&:empty?)` removes those that are empty.

Comment: What if `arr = [[nil, nil], [nil, 3], [], nil, [1]]`? (The question is not clear about that.)  Depending on what is required, maybe `ary.compact.reject { |a| a.compact.empty? unless a.empty? }.map(&:compact) #=> [[3], [], [1]]`.  I see you are closing in on rolling five nines.